# How to access electron-settings unexported interfaces and types

Tags: typescript, electron

In [this definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/electron-settings/index.d.ts), the return type of the `set` method is specified as `JsonValue`.

I'd like to give my variable this type too, but I dont know how to access JsonValue.

### Example

```
import settings = require("electron-settings");

let value: JsonValue = settings.get("abc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is not to type the variable explicitly, you can let the compiler infer

```
import settings = require("electron-settings");

let value = settings.get("abc");
```

You can use a type query and the `ReturnType` conditional type to define the type of `value` relative to the return type of `get`:

```
import settings = require("electron-settings");

let value: ReturnType<typeof settings['get']> = settings.get("abc");
```

You could even use a type alias so you can easily reuse it in more places:

```
import settings = require("electron-settings");
type JsonValue  =  ReturnType<typeof settings['get']>;
let value:JsonValue = settings.get("abc");
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types